# Merge specific commit from official repo into local repo

Tags: git, github, merge, fetch, pull

Suppose on 1st Jan, I forked (`origin`) and cloned(local) a github repo(`upstream`). I created a branch `X` on its `master`. And, started working on `X`. Over the time, I kept pushing the commits to `origin`.

I kept updating `origin`'s `master` from `upstream`'s `master`. (via my local repo).

There was a bug on `master` when I made branch `X`, and consequently, `X` currently has this bug. Recently, `upstream`'s master branch was updated with a commit providing a bug-fix for that bug.

My question is: How do I pull this specific commit onto my `X`?

`master` branches of `upstream` & `origin` both are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. Rebase `X` onto `upstream/master`.
2. Merge `upstream/master` into `X`.
3. Cherry-pick the specific commit (let's call it `<sha fix>`) into `X`.

Before you choose any of these, be sure to fetch the changes from upstream first:

```bash
# First fetch upstream/master
$ git fetch upstream
```

Then here are the commands for your various options:

#### Rebase

```bash
$ git rebase upstream/master X
```

#### Merge

```bash
# With X checked out
$ git merge upstream/master
```

#### Cherry-pick

```bash
# With X checked out
$ git cherry-pick <sha fix>
```

In general, I recommend using `rebase` to bring branches in sync with their upstream branches, but you may decide that you want to use `merge` instead.  I don't recommend using `cherry-pick` for this, because if you're going to eventually merge `X` back into `master`, you'll end up duplicating commits, which can cause code regressions in some cases.

Comment: on the other hand, i would recommend to use cherry-pick in this case. merge will pull in all the changes from the upstream branch and i think you do not want this. (if you want all changes, this is imho the way to go). i ask users to be careful with rebase because it has the potential to mess up things rather badly. cherry-pick is ideal for ad-hock integration of single commits (or maybe a few of them). i never had problems with later merges including the same commits. all approaches work and it is a matter of personal preference.